# Group action on a subset and permutes one element out of the subset

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am thinking about the situation if a group $G$ acts on a set $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ by left multiplication where $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are cosets, so that we have a homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_5$. Suppose there is a $g\in G$ such that $\phi(g)$ will move $4$ to $5$. What is the group action $\phi'$ of $G$ on $X'=\{1,2,3,4\}$ by left multiplication?

I know $\phi'$ is a homomorphism between $G$ and $S_4$. However, the same $g$ under the group action by left multiplication will move $4$ to $5$, but $5$ is not in $X'$.

Comment: I'm guessing (completely guessing) that $\;X\;$ is then a complete set of representatives of (left, say) cosets of some subgroup of index five in $\;G\;$ ...right?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes

Comment: Well, if I understood correctly, then there is no such action on the same subset $\;X'\;$ of the original one. Just suppose $\;G\;$ has a subgroup of index five but not one of index four...

Comment: There is no "group action" of $G$ on $X'$, because the action of $g$ is not a permutation on $X'$. It doesn't make sense to talk about "the group of action $\phi'$ of $G$ on $X'$ in this case.

Comment: By definition, a (left) group action of $G$ on a set $S$ is a map $f\colon G\times S\to S$ such that $f(g,(h,s)) = f(gh,s)$ for all $g,h\in G$, $s\in S$, and $f(e,s) = s$ for all $s\in S$. In particular, $f(g,s)$ must be an element of $s$.

Comment: @DonAntonio@Arturo Magidin Thank you very much. I understand it now.